# Proving that no integer has multiplicative order 40 (mod 100)

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I am trying to prove that no integer has multiplicative order 40 (mod 100), so far I have listed the facts that I know:

$\phi(100) = 40$, this means that for any integer $a$ relatively prime to $100$ we definitely have $a^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$ by Euler's theorem. Furthermore, the order of $a \pmod{b}$ must divide $40$; therefore, we can never have an order that is more than $40$.

However, I am unable to prove that it can not be $40$?

**Edit:** I am unable to understand the notation used in the answers below since I have only studied the bare minimum of elementaty number theory, but I think I got the idea:

We have $a^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$
and  $a^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ since $4$ and $25$ are coprime. However, $a^{40}$must still be coprime to both 25 and 4, not sure how to prove this but I think it is natural since $100$ had them as divisors and $a^{40}$ was coprime to 100. Inspecting the two new equations we have $\phi(4) = 2$; therefore, the order of $a$ must not be more than 2 now.

Edit: I just realized it doesn't make sense to say not more than 2 since we are looking for $\pmod{100}$....not sure where to go from here?

Please correct if my proof is incorrect, thank you.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: yea I know it but how would you apply it? Don't you need two modulus?

Comment: Yeah, as below, try 25 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a direct proof: in 
$$(\mathbf Z/100\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq(\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z)^\times\times(\mathbf Z/25\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/20\mathbf Z,$$
(the last groups are the *additive groups*), an element $(a,b)$ has order the l.c.m. of the orders of $a$ and $b$, which are divisors of $2$ and $20$, hence  a divisor of $\;\operatorname{lcm}(2,20)=20$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\Bbb{Z}/100 \cong \mathbb{Z}/25 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$ so $$(\Bbb{Z}/100)^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/25)^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/4)^\times.$$
Now suppose there is an element of order $40$ and try to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem,

$\displaystyle (10x+y)^{10}= \sum _{k=0}^{10}{10 \choose k}10^{k}x^{k}y^{10-k} \equiv$
$\tag A {\displaystyle  y^{10} + {10 \choose 1} 10 x y^9+0 \equiv y^{10} \pmod{100}}$

Examining the $40$ units $a \in (\mathbf Z/100\mathbf Z)^\times$ taken $10$ at a time:

**Case 1** (1); $\quad a = [10t + 1] \text{ where } 0 \le t \le 9$:

By $\text{(A)}$, $a^{10} = 1$ and the order of $a$ divides $10$.

**Case 2** (9); $\quad a = [10t - 1] \text{ where } 1 \le t \le 10$:

By $\text{(A)}$, $a^{10} = 1$ and the order of $a$ divides $10$.

**Case 3** (3); $\quad a = [10t + 3] \text{ where } 0 \le t \le 9$:

By Case 2 we can write

$\quad  3^{20} = (3^2)^{10} = 9^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$

But by $\text{(A)}$, $a^{10} = [3]^{10}$ and so $a^{20} = 1$ and the order of $a$ divides $20$.

**Case 4** (7); $\quad a = [10t - 3] \text{ where } 1 \le t \le 10$:

By $\text{(A)}$, $a^{10} = [-3]^{10}$ but then also

$ {([-3]^{10})}^2 = {([3]^{10})}^2 = [3]^{20} $

But then by Case 3 we conclude that $a^{20} = 1$ and the order of $a$ divides $20$.